# Usage of which in English

Tags: grammar, word-usage, american-english, british-english, syntactic-analysis

In Barron's ACT guide, I was stumped by the following: "Man alone was endowed by imagination, which was bound to complicate matters for him" was stated grammatically incorrect. Why  would that be the case? What should be the correct syntax structure?

Comment: "Endowed with".

Comment: A helpful way to keep the relevant prepositions for "endowed" straight is to consider the wording "All men are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable rights." Here, "by" introduces the party responsible for providing the endowment or gift (namely, "their Creator") and "with" introduces  the endowment or gift itself (in this case "certain unalienable rights"). In your sentence, "imagination" is the endowment or gift, not the source of the endowment or gift; hence "with" (not "by") is the proper preposition to use.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is Barron's ACT guide, and what does *it* say why the sentence is ungrammatical? Or is it just going around labeling random things grammatical and ungrammatical, never explaining its reasoning?

Comment: You should try this question at [English Language Learners.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com) after you add all sorts of context from the ACT guide.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the quoted sentence is that 'with', not 'by' is the correct preposition to follow 'endowed', when talking about possession of a trait or quality.

[Endow with (Macmillan)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/endow-with)